# input disable text entry on copy and paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function works well, however it currently stops pasting text and number. 
Is there a way of stopping only text inside the input?

```
var restrictInputToDigits = function(){
    $('.digits').keypress(function(key) {
        if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;
    });
    $('.digits').bind('copy paste', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

I would like digits to be pasted in as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the value of text field. Then replace all characters except number by empty character. This should help

```js
$('.digits').on('change keyup',function(){
     var value = $(this).val().toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
     $(this).val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="digits">
```

Comment: Almost completely same answer as that of Mooseman. With the same possible problem, if I might add.

Comment: Yes, But I posted before updating his post.

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('.digits').on('change keyup paste', function(e){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.val($this.val().replace(/\D+/, ''));
  if(e.charCode < 48 || e.charCode > 57){ e.preventDefault(); return false; }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="digits" value="1234">
```

Comment: This shows the entered text and THEN removes it. This is bad user experience.

Comment: `keyup` is sufficient.